# Adding meshes to detected transform

Tags: rviz, urdf, ros-melodic, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.2
DISTRO: Melodic

I have a small custom mobile robot with a Intel Realsense d435i on it to perform machine vision tasks such as object recognition and grasping. The node I've written to accomplish this classifies objects it comes across on a course and puts out a transform of the object's pose. It publishes the transform as "large_box_1", "large_box_2", etc. When I pull the RobotModel in RVIZ, I'm able to load a robot description I've described in the URDF.

What I'd like to do is take the meshes for the "large_box" I've created, and overlay them on the transforms in RVIZ. This would give better visualization of how accurately the robot is classifying these poses. How would I set this up?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330380/adding-meshes-to-detected-transform/) by [lauesa](https://answers.ros.org/users/38765/lauesa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're detection node can broadcast an unique tf_frame for each object then you can also publish a [Marker message](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker#Mesh_Resource_.28MESH_RESOURCE.3D10.29_.5B1.1.2B-.5D) containing a mesh resource in that frame. You could also color tint or use transparency so that this model doesn't cover up your original point data.

This method means you can use any STL / DAE file to represent the detected objects, maybe not needed for simple boxes but could be very useful for more complex shapes.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lauesa](https://answers.ros.org/users/38765/lauesa/) on 2019-08-12**:
This solution worked very well for my purposes. Thanks for your help!